# Change background color of cells of table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have got a table with 6 rows and x columns. I need to change background color of cells to color which contains in array. Index of color matches how many rows should be painted. I have next array of colors:

```
var arr = ["lightgreen", "orange", "red"];
```

And my jQuery script:

```
$.each(arr, function(index, val) {
$("tr:eq(" + (index) + ")").css("background-color", val);
});
```

This piece of code only paint first three rows in different colors.
I need output table like this:

```
lightgreen lightgreen lightgreen lightgreen
orange orange orange orange
orange orange orange orange
red red red red
red red red red
red red red red
```

My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kvdokq13/

Comment: Why do you expect that output? What's the logic you're trying to implement? Because without that it's hard to extrapolate this to any other  generic situation, or answer this question without hard-coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to process *N rows* at each time, while using `$("tr:eq(" + (index) + ")")` only selects the *unique Nth* row!

You can achieve it like this:

```
var arr = ["lightgreen", "orange", "red"];
var $rows = $('tr');
var nextRow = 0;
$.each(arr, function(index, val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < index + 1; i++) {
    $rows.eq(nextRow++).css("background-color", val);
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kvdokq13/6/

For a more general use, note that this should be enhanced to properly take care of differences between the array length and the number of rows: currently it assumes that there are exactly `(1 + 2 + ... + N)` rows!

Answer (score 0):

modified Azim's asnwer...

```
var arr = ["lightgreen", "orange", "red"];
var tr = $('table tr');

for (var i=0; i<tr.length; i++){
  $(tr[i]).css("background-color", arr[i]);
   if (i>2){
        $(tr[i]).css("background-color", arr[2]);
  }    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kvdokq13/5/

this could be more efficient using only css but I am guessing that JQuery is a must?

Answer (score 0):

You should hold number how much rows you need to skip:

```
var arr = ["lightgreen", "orange", "red"];
var skip = 0;
$.each(arr, function(index, val) {
    var _repeat = index+1; // js arrays are zero indexed
    for (var i = 0; i < _repeat; i++) 
        $("tr:eq(" + (i+skip) + ")").css("background-color", val);
  skip = skip + _repeat;
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzumq60e/1/)

Answer (score 0):

While you've already accepted an answer to this question, I thought I'd throw in an alternative using plain JavaScript, rather than a library, just in case that might be useful.

Note that I've used some ECMAScript 6 features, the 'fat arrow' syntax and `Array.from()` (see the references below), though I'll post an alternative (below the 'primary' part of my answer to show an alternative implementation if you'd rather not use ES6 just yet).

That said, my own solution is the follwing:

```
// the colors Array:
var colors = ["lightgreen", "orange", "red"],
// a reference to the <table> element that is
// to be coloured:
  table = document.querySelector('table');

// declaring the relevant function to handle the 
// colouring:
function colorNRows(arr, table) {

  // caching the rows of the table:
  var rows = table.rows,

  // using Array.from() to convert the HTMLCollection
  // into an Array:
    clone = Array.from(rows),

  // iterating over the array of colours, using
  // Array.prototype.map(),
  // row:   the array-element of the array over which
  //        we're iterating,
  // index: the index of the current array-element
  //        in that array,
  // array: (unused here), the array over which we're
  //        iterating.
    segments = arr.map(function(row, index, array) {

      // removing 'index+1' elements of the array from
      // the clone Array, starting at index 0 and
      // returning the removed row(s) to form a new
      // Array:
      return clone.splice(0, index + 1);

    // iterating over the newly-formed Array,
    // using Array.prototype.forEach();
    // the automagically-passed array-elements
    // are, as above, the array-element (of the new
    // array) and the index of the current
    // array-element (in that array):
    }).forEach(function(rowSegments, index) {

      // here we iterate over the array(s) held
      // in each array-element, again using the
      // automagic variables are the same as above
      // relative to the current array.

      // we're using the 'fat arrow' syntax to pass
      // the array-element (toColor) into the
      // the process on the right hand side, thereby
      // styling the backgroundColor of each array-element
      // (a <tr>) according to the color held in the 'arr'
      // array, at the index held in the outer forEach():
      rowSegments.forEach(toColor => toColor.style.backgroundColor = arr[index]);
    });
}

// calling the function:
colorNRows(colors, table);
```

```js
var colors = ["lightgreen", "orange", "red"],
  table = document.querySelector('table');

function colorNRows(arr, table) {
  var rows = table.rows,
    clone = Array.from(rows),
    segments = arr.map(function(row, index, array) {
      return clone.splice(0, index + 1);
    }).forEach(function(rowSegments, index) {
      rowSegments.forEach(toColor => toColor.style.backgroundColor = arr[index]);
    });
}

colorNRows(colors, table);
```

```html
<table border="4" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>39</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>41</td>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>46</td>
    <td>47</td>
    <td>48</td>
    <td>49</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>51</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>53</td>
    <td>54</td>
    <td>55</td>
    <td>56</td>
    <td>57</td>
    <td>58</td>
    <td>59</td>
    <td>60</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/srv21gmo/).

Removing the ES6 features, to be compatible with the majority of modern browsers, leaves us with the following (everything but the commented code is precisely the same):

```
function colorNRows(arr, table) {
  var rows = table.rows,

  // cloning the rows HTMLCollection, using
  // Array.prototype.slice() in conjunction with
  // Function.prototype.call(), to allow us to use
  // slice() on the Array-like collection:
    clone = Array.prototype.slice.call(rows, 0),

    segments = arr.map(function(row, index, array) {
      return clone.splice(0, index + 1);
    }).forEach(function(rowSegments, index) {

      // here, rather than a fat arrow function,
      // we explicitly use an inner forEach() loop
      // performing the same action, but slightly
      // more verbose:
      rowSegments.forEach(function(toColor) {
        toColor.style.backgroundColor = arr[index];
      })
    });
}
```

```js
var colors = ["lightgreen", "orange", "red"],
  table = document.querySelector('table');

function colorNRows(arr, table) {
  var rows = table.rows,
    clone = Array.prototype.slice.call(rows, 0),
    segments = arr.map(function(row, index, array) {
      return clone.splice(0, index + 1);
    }).forEach(function(rowSegments, index) {
      rowSegments.forEach(function(toColor) {
        toColor.style.backgroundColor = arr[index];
      })
    });
}

colorNRows(colors, table);
```

```html
<table border="4" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>39</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>41</td>
    <td>42</td>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>46</td>
    <td>47</td>
    <td>48</td>
    <td>49</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>51</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>53</td>
    <td>54</td>
    <td>55</td>
    <td>56</td>
    <td>57</td>
    <td>58</td>
    <td>59</td>
    <td>60</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/srv21gmo/1/).

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/from).
- [Arrow ('fat arrow') functions: `=>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/).
- [`HTMLTableElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement).
- [`HTMLTableElement.rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows).